kotlin How to implement Room multiplatform alpha06
expect object AppDatabaseConstructor : RoomDatabaseConstructor
actual object AppDatabaseConstructor : RoomDatabaseConstructor {
override fun initialize(): AppDatabase{

How implemet this????
}
}
import androidx.room.ConstructedBy
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import androidx.room.RoomDatabaseConstructor
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

const val DATABASE_NAME = "movie.db"

@Database(entities = [Movie::class], version = 1)
@ConstructedBy(AppDatabaseConstructor::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getDao(): MovieDao
}

expect object AppDatabaseConstructor : RoomDatabaseConstructor<AppDatabase>

@Dao
interface MovieDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(item: Movie)

    @Query("SELECT count(*) FROM Movie")
    suspend fun count(): Int

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Movie")
    fun getAllAsFlow(): Flow<List<Movie>>
}

@Entity
data class Movie(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val overview: String,
    val releaseDate: String,
    val poster: String,
    val backdrop: String?,
    val originalTitle: String,
    val originalLanguage: String,
    val popularity: Double,
    val voteAverage: Double,
    val isFavorite: Boolean

)

I try all I can but nothing is working I am very lost Thank you

At the moment in the version of "room - multiplatform 2.7.0-alpha06" I have not found the solution if someone can help,  It is about implementing "actual" correctly for android and IOS. thank you very much.

KSP will generate the actual implementations for different targets, however I haven't got it to work completely yet either and get: Object 'MyDatabaseConstructor' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member 'initialize'
